# Integration between Multiple Enterprise Blockchains (Hyperledger, Quorum, Corda) -- Through the use of Ethereum oracles?

Tags: quorum

Many organisations are running proof of concepts with different enterprise blockchain technologies -- Quorum, Corda and Hyperledger.

Understand that most efficiency gains can be unlocked only when everyone adopts a single blockchain -- is this contestable?

If history is of any guide at all, the future will be one of multiple blockchain technologies.

Reconciliation across multiple systems is streamlined via the use of blockchain. If one needs to reconcile between 2 blockchain nodes (say, one Quorum node and another hyperledger node), the efficiency gains are lost.

Hyperledger Node will make an REST/JSON API call to Quorum and vice versa. How then can one reconcile both transactions on each ledgers which reside on different networks? Should one perform this integration via Oracles or?